# Getting unexpected data while setting up Analytics Service

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently attempting to setup Google analytics for a mobile app I'm creating and I'm seeing a bunch of unexpected data. I've just started setting this up so I am the only one using the analytics and there is no way anyone else has access to my app or my google analytics property id. However, I'm seeing data come in from around the world.

Why am I seeing data from all of these countries and how do I stop this 'bogus data' from coming in? Thanks for the help.

This is a shot from my dashboard showing all of the data coming in:
[image: Data from around the world]

Comment: I considered this, but the difference is that my app is currently only being run locally so no one else should be able to access it at all. The only data that I should be getting is from what I'm doing on my local machine.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The spam that you are experiencing works in exactly that way (they are unofficially called ghost referrers). They are app/website agnostic, and so just target the property ID that you have for your app. You can read more from this site: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/